# iOS - Xcode 4 Missing Files in Project

Tags: xcode4

At some point I must have moved files from one location to another using Finder (not Xcode). Now Xcode constantly complains that the files are missing from the original directory. In the Errors portion of Xcode, under "Project" it lists a dozen or so "Missing files" all labeled in red. How do I let Xcode know that the move was intentional and that these files aren't actually missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case anyone else runs into this problem: My project was source controlled. Although I had never committed the project, Xcode was complaining about the non-existence of the moved files in the original directory (the directory I originally had the files in before they were moved). What frustrated the situation was that the files didn't even show up as red in the Project Navigator, Xcode would only complain about their non-existence in the Issue Navigator. To solve the problem, I had to go into my source control program (in my case, Cornerstone) and delete the files from the original directory there. The fact that the project was source controlled was the real issue.

Answer (score 0):

just select the red-highlighted files in the navigator, and press delete. They will be removed instantly, not prompted for 'files or reference'.